# Extract address fraction for later use in a C# class

Tags: c#, replace, match, street-address

I need to see if my address contains certain fractions, but not all.  Addresses like Hwy 1/158 should not match.  For now I'm just matching to 1/4, 1/2, 3/4.  I may add to the list later depending on data, but for now that will handle the vast majority of my issues.

Currently I'm just testing for "1/2" like so

```
if (Address.Contains("1/2"))
{
    Address = Address.Replace("1/2", "");
    Fraction = "1/2";
}
```

How can I match for multiple fractions, remove those fractions, save the fraction match to later be assigned to Fraction?

Comment: Make a list of fractions that you want to replace, search for each of them, and replace/save it when you find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) method to match multiple patterns and use its evaluator to save matched element:

```
var fractions = new[] { "1/2", "1/4", "3/4" };
var address = "Street 1/4";
List<string> matched = new List<string>();
string replaced = Regex.Replace(address, string.Join("|", fractions), match =>
{
    matched.Add(match.Value);;
    return string.Empty;
});
```